# rsync to much upload data

Tags: backup, rsync, synology, incremental-backup

I have an issue with an incremental backup using rsync. My issue rsync that it sends 150 GB of data to the backup server, however only 10 GB maximum have been changed on the server. I can't figure out why rsync is sending these 150 GB of data instead of 10 GB, as the backup is supposed to be incremental.

Can somebody point out any mistakes in this command:

> rsync -avh --exclude '#recycle' --rsync-path="rsync" --log-file="/var/tmp/rsync.log"  /volume1/Backups -e 'ssh -p 1432' remote@remoteIP:/home/backups --delete

I'm running it on my synology server.

Comment: Your command transfer every changed file. If the file ist 150GB big it will be retransfered. You can try --inplace, if it works depends however of the File. If its encrypted, compressed it wont help.

Comment: Hi, I've found out that my rsync works perfectly. It has been shown that it took full backup of all systems.